# POST of JSON data not working the same with requests as with curl

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest

I have problem with post method of REST in python. 
when i am invoking REST API post method from curl it is working but when i invoke same from python program i have bad request 400 error.

The following curl command works:

```
curl -k -d  @data.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v  https://dsp.corpo.t-mobile.pl/npitapi/pn/saveAll
```

Data id data.json file

```
[{
        "msisdn": "483260321",
        "date_from": "2019-04-25T18:30:00.000+0000",
        "date_to": "2019-04-24T18:30:00.000+0000",
        "opr_recpn_id": 5,
        "date_last": "2019-04-21T18:30:00.000+0000"
}]
```

My python code:

```
 import json
 import httplib
 import requests
 from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
 requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

 url = 'https://dsp.corpo.t-mobile.pl/npitapi/pn/saveAll';

 pay= {'msisdn': '483260329',
    'date_from': '2019-04-25T18:30:00.000+0000',
    'date_to': '2019-04-24T18:30:00.000+0000',
    'opr_recpn_id': 5,
    'date_last': '2019-04-21T18:30:00.000+0000'}

 response = requests.post(url, json=pay,verify=False) 
 print(response)


 output response:

 <Response [400]>
```

Can somebody help me what is the issue in data ?
i think json data is correct and it is same what i have in curl command.

Comment: From curl you send a list with one entry which is a dict. From python you send a dict.

Comment: In the first one you're sending a single element list containing a dict as its first element.  In the second example you're sending just a dict.  The question is; Which does the API expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://dsp.corpo.t-mobile.pl/npitapi/pn/saveAll'
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json"
}

pay= [{'msisdn': '483260329',
'date_from': '2019-04-25T18:30:00.000+0000',
'date_to': '2019-04-24T18:30:00.000+0000',
'opr_recpn_id': 5,
'date_last': '2019-04-21T18:30:00.000+0000'}]

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(pay), headers=headers) 
print(response)
```

Can you try this?

Comment: This is sent automatically by requests when using the `json=` keyword argument. See https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests  "Using the `json` parameter in the request will change the Content-Type in the header to `application/json`."

Comment: I added primarily for headers.

Comment: Also already tried it but it did not work. i have checked all the possibilities given in google but still the issue.

Comment: Are you using Python2? Can you try the updated script(Python3)? Still 400?

Comment: Thanks!! It is working now. Can you please explain me why it was not working with my code ?

Comment: Seems more like `pay` being `array` instead of being an JSON Object(Dict in Python). I stripped away all the unnecessary code to debug and added headers. Incorrect headers also cause errors sometimes in Spring framework.(depends on backend config. actually)

Like they say: Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.